# Cypress chaining DOM elements - property 'then' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: jquery, dom, cypress, element, chaining

In the below code, the first "then" works fine and indicates no issues, but the *second* "then" is throwing " property 'then' does not exist on type 'JQuery' -- why is this happening and how can I fix it? Seems like the code should work just fine

```
cy.get('.bp3-datepicker').eq(0).then((popup) => { 
    popup.find('.DayPicker').eq(0).then((item) => {
        // <item do stuff>
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `wrap()` to yield the object

```js
cy.get('.bp3-datepicker').eq(0).then((popup) => { 
    cy.wrap(popup).find('.DayPicker').eq(0).then((item) => {
        // <item do stuff>
    })
})
```

OR, you can also do:

```
cy.get(".bp3-datepicker")
  .eq(0)
  .find(".DayPicker")
  .eq(0)
  .then((item) => {
    // <item do stuff>
  })
```